# Biased graph generating processes

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs, algorithmic-randomness

Given a random process (algorithm) that is supposed to generate with equal probability graphs from a given class $\Gamma$. Assume the process is not *obviously* biased, i.e. generating graphs unevenly (giving for example some graph properties a stronger weight).

How can it be checked or *proved* that the algorithm doesn't generate a finite amount of graphs with some property which in fact [almost never](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) occurs in $\Gamma$?

A related question is [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/how-to-prove-correctness-of-a-shuffle-algorithm) one.

Comment: It will generally be very hard to answer without more details. One common approach in the dense random graphs is to use the moment method. In the sparse configuration model, a common method is the differential equation method. I can not say with authority but I doubt that there is a general method to prove an almost sure(never) statement.

Comment: @SumanChakraborty: My question is more about algorithms (and proofs of correctness) than about statements. Unfortunately, I cannot provide more details. I know there is a lot of literature on the correctness of *deterministic* algorithms. I am looking for information on the correctness of *random* algorithms. What are principles to check this?

Answer (score 2):

The method(s) will very much depend on the problem at hand, let me share few articles to make the point clear:

1. [Finding Hidden Cliques in Linear Time with High Probability](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/combinatorics-probability-and-computing/article/abs/finding-hidden-cliques-in-linear-time-with-high-probability/88A05D6B07878D54E62433DA72190623) (DEKEL
   , GUREL-GUREVICH and PERES).

Here they proposed an algorithm to find a planted clique and showed that it works with a probability bounded below by a constant.

2. [Limits of local algorithms over sparse random graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1831.pdf) by GAMARNIK AND SUDAN.

Here they proved that certain algorithms will not succeed to find the largest independent set in sparse random graphs with high probability.